# Don't understand vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void SaveNumbers(vector<int> numbers);

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    SaveNumbers(numbers);

    cout << "FROM MAIN FUNCTION:" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << numbers.at(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

void SaveNumbers(vector<int> numbers)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        numbers.push_back(i + 1);
    }
    cout << "FROM FUNCTION: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << numbers.at(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//OUTPUT:
/*
FROM FUNCTION:
1 2 3 4 5
FROM MAIN FUNCTION:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
*/
```

When I use vector in void function then vector has memory and I get expected result. When I use vector in main function, then program causes an error message. What should I do to pass the memory from void function vector to main function vetor without leaking it.

Answer (score 5):

`SaveNumbers` needs to take the `vector` by reference, otherwise the calling code won't see the changes.

```
void SaveNumbers(vector<int> & numbers);
```

You can see this with a toy example

```
void byVal(int n) { n = 42; }

void byRef(int &n) { n = 42; }

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  byVal(a);
  cout << a; // prints 0
  byRef(a);
  cout << a; // prints 42
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the parameter of the function does not have a referenced type

```
void SaveNumbers(vector<int> numbers);
```

then it means that the function gets its argument by value that is the function deal with a copy of the passed to it argument.

You have to declare the parameter as having referenced type

```
void SaveNumbers(vector<int> &numbers);
```

Also this loop in main

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << numbers.at(i) << " ";
}
```

uses magic number 5. Such a loop is an unsafe loop.

You could write instead

```
for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++ )
{
    std::cout << numbers[i] << " ";
}
```

But it will be even better to use the range-based for loop

```
for ( const auto &item : numbers )
{
    std::cout << item << " ";
}
```

Within the function to avoid memory reallocation of the internal memory of the vector you could initially declare the vector as having 5 elements or to reserve memory for 5 elements. For example

```
numbers.resize( 5 );
for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++ )
{
    numbers[i] = i + 1;
}
```

or

```
numbers.reserve( 5 );

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    numbers.push_back(i + 1);
}
```

Or you could use the standard algorithm `std::iota` declared in the header `<numeric>`.